# Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Data\Form::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, template

I am developing a custom module for Magento 2.

Right now I have an error. When I run the *Place Order* in checkout page,
it is supposed to redirect me to a page where it says "You will be redirected to somewhere" for 5 seconds, and then redirect to the "somewhere".

But, I am getting this error in var/report

> Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Data\Form::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory, none given, called in C:\Apache24\htdocs\mag\app\code\Asiapay\Pdcptb\Block\Redirect.php on line 34 and defined in C:\Apache24\htdocs\mag\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Form.php on line 59

I have no idea why it shows this. Is there anything that I missed? I've tried to delete the `var/generation` content, so I'm sure it is not the that problem.

**Block file** (`app\code\Asiapay\Pdcptb\Block\Redirect.php`):

```
<?php

namespace Asiapay\Pdcptb\Block;

use Asiapay\Pdcptb\Model\PdcptbFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

//use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context;

class Redirect extends AbstractBlock
{
    /**
     * @var PdcptbFactory
     */
    protected $_modelPdcptbFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PdcptbFactory $modelPdcptbFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_modelPdcptbFactory = $modelPdcptbFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $pdcptb = $this->_modelPdcptbFactory->create();

        $form = new Form();
        $form->setAction($pdcptb->getUrl())
            ->setId('pdcptb_checkout')
            ->setName('pdcptb_checkout')
            ->setMethod('post')
            ->setUseContainer(true);
        foreach ($pdcptb->getCheckoutFormFields() as $field => $value) {
            $form->addField($field, 'hidden', ['name' => $field, 'value' => $value]);
        }
        $html = '<html><body>';
        $html .= __('You will be redirected to the payment gateway in a few     seconds.');
        $html .= $form->toHtml();
        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">require(["jquery", "prototype"], function(jQuery) {document.getElementById("pdcptb_checkout").submit();})</script>';

        $html .= '</body></html>';

        return $html;

    }
}
```

**Controller file** (`app\code\Asiapay\Pdcptb\Controller\Pdcptb\Redirect.php`):

```
<?php

namespace Asiapay\Pdcptb\Controller\Pdcptb;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw\Interceptor;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class Redirect extends AbstractPdcptb
{
    /**
     * @var RawFactory
     */
    protected $_resultRawFactory;

    /**
     * @var LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $_viewLayoutFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        LayoutFactory $viewLayoutFactory
    ) {
        $this->_resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        $this->_viewLayoutFactory = $viewLayoutFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * When a customer chooses Pdcptb on Checkout/Payment page
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        /*      METHOD 1        */

        $session = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $session->setPdcptbQuoteId($session->getQuoteId());
        $this->_resultRawFactory->create()->setContents($this->_viewLayoutFactory->create()->createBlock('Asiapay\Pdcptb\Block\Redirect')->toHtml());
        $session->unsQuoteId();
    }
}
```

**Template file** (`app\code\Asiapay\Pdcptb\view\frontend\templates\form.phtml`):

```
<fieldset class="form-list">
    <?php $_code = $this->getMethodCode() ?>
    <ul id="payment_form_<?php echo $_code ?>" style="display:none">
        <li>
            <?php echo __('You will be redirected to a secure payment page.') ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Tried to delete `var/generation` folder?

Comment: I suggest you to check to C:\Apache24\htdocs\mag\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Form.php because it giving error due to "new Form()"

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i have mentioned **i have tried doing so** please read

Comment: @BhupendraJadeja `C:\Apache24\htdocs\mag\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Form.php` is Magento's folder, not my custom module, u sure i need to modify this file?

Comment: No i am not telling to change the file of Form.php but i think you will need to check for the reference as you are create new Form which is not object of that file

Answer (score 3):

You can't instantiate an object of form without passing argument. Please refer file `Magento\Framework\Data\Form.php` wherein construct function there are four arguments (one is an array) so you must pass three arguments during initiate object of Form:

```
 class Form extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\AbstractForm
 {
     public function __construct(
         Factory $factoryElement,
         ElementCollectionFactory $factoryCollection,
         FormKey $formKey,
         $data = []
     ) {
         parent::__construct($factoryElement, $factoryCollection, $data);
         $this->_allElements = $this->_factoryCollection-create(['container' => $this]);
         $this->formKey = $formKey;
     }
 }
```

Your argument is **not matching** with construct function.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code. See injected form factory into constructor, see form creation in `_toHtml()` method:

```
class Redirect extends AbstractBlock
{
    /**
     * @var PdcptbFactory
     */
    protected $_modelPdcptbFactory;
    protected $_formFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PdcptbFactory $modelPdcptbFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_modelPdcptbFactory = $modelPdcptbFactory;
        $this->_formFactory = $formFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $pdcptb = $this->_modelPdcptbFactory->create();
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(); // instead of "new Form()"
        $form->setAction($pdcptb->getUrl());
```